# How to indentify image download size?

Tags: image, download, size

I have a image link ( https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20200714180638/CIP_Launch-banner.png ) of size 83130 bytes on my system. But I get 5616998bytes(taken from geeksforgeeks) on somewhere else. My question is this, why there is difference between the size of same image. How can I identify the download size of image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image we download isn't original. we get a copy of it if we download it from the website. Downloading from the sources folder of websites gives you the image of original size.

Comment: Shivam Sharma! That means my device is showing correct size.

Comment: Yes Your device is showing correct size.